# Java Find and Replace String using Regex

Tags: java

I need to specify the **string find** in Regex format, in order that head tag can be found whatever its format is like `<html >` or `<html>` or `< html>`. How to specify the find string in Regex format?

```
String source = "<html >The quick brown fox jumps over the brown lazy dog.</html >";
String find = "<html>";
String replace = "";        
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(find);        
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);        
String output = matcher.replaceAll(replace); 
System.out.println("Source = " + source);
System.out.println("Output = " + output);
```

Comment: Is `<html <!-- <html> --> >` valid html?

Answer (score 3):

Although you could go round your problem by doing `<\\s*html\\s*>`, you **should not** process HTML with regex. [Obligatory link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

The `\\s*` denotes 0 or more white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to parse HTML using regex! Try reading about `XPath`. Very helpful.
Although `XPath` will try by default to validate your document, but you can try `HtmlCleaner` to make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

To extract text inside your tags use something like

```
String source = "<html >The quick brown fox jumps over the brown lazy dog.</html >";
System.out.println( source.replaceAll( "^<\\s*html\\s*>(.*)<\\s*\\/html\\s*>$", "$1" ) );
// output is:
// The quick brown fox jumps over the brown lazy dog.
```

But try to avoid parsing of html by regexps. Read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

This example may be helpful to you.

```
String source = "<html >The quick brown fox jumps over the brown lazy dog.</html >";

        String find = "\\<.*?>";
        String replace = "";        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(find);        
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);        
        String output = matcher.replaceAll(replace); 
        System.out.println("Source = " + source);
        System.out.println("Output = " + output);
```